# Need to add variables to SOAP request without SAVON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I need to be able to add variables to the following XML from the server-side.  Is there a way to do this?  I cannot use SAVON to handle the request.

```
data = <<-EOF
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <CheckoutShoppingCart xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1">
      <Request>
        <XMLDetail>Full</XMLDetail>
        <ClientID><!-- client_id goes here --></ClientID>            
      </Request>
    </CheckoutShoppingCart>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
EOF

result= http.post(uri.path, data)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = <<-EOF
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <CheckoutShoppingCart xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1">
      <Request>
        <XMLDetail>Full</XMLDetail>
        <ClientID>#{client_id}</ClientID>            
      </Request>
    </CheckoutShoppingCart>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
EOF
```

Comment: I do not know why I didn't just try that first -_-

Comment: Great answer, but for future readers it could help explaining why this works ;)

Comment: It works coz it is a simple string builder, like "Hello:#{name}"